# Excel formula not accepting on Google sheet (Custom Number format )

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[<1000], 0; [>=1000]0.0, "K"; [>=1000000]0.0,, "Million";[>=1000000000]0.0,,, "Billion"

i have checked this formula with chatgpt also & it has told me that the formula is correct, i want to display number in a data range. But google sheet is not accepting the formula it is showing invalid formula.

what i want to show-

1-if the value is less than 1000 the value would be displayed as it is, For example, if the value is 500 or 999, it will be displayed as "500" or"999".
2-if the value is greater than or equal to 1,000 but less than 1 million. It would be displayed with "K" as Suffix. For example, if the value is 3,500, it will be displayed as "3.5K."
3-if the value is greater than or equal to 1,000,000 (1 million) but less than 1 billion. It would have "Million" as Suffix. For example, if the value is 5,500,000, it will be displayed as "5.5 Million."
4-if the value is greater than or equal to 1,000,000,000 (1 billion). It would have "Billion" as Suffix.For example, if the value is 2,500,000,000, it will be displayed as "2.5 Billion."

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    IFS(
        A1:A >= 1000000000,
        A1:A / 1000000000 &
            " Billion",
        A1:A >= 1000000,
        A1:A / 1000000 &
            " Million",
        A1:A >= 1000,
        A1:A / 1000 & " K",
        A1:A < 1000,
        A1:A
    )
)
```

Here is a screenshot of the results:

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0):

In this context when you say formula I’m assuming you are referring to writing a custom number format and not an actual formula, given the formatting you’ve provided.

**When using the custom number formatting, only two conditions can be applied.** See [Ben Collin’s complete guide to custom formatting](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-custom-number-format/) (scroll down to the “Google Sheets Custom Number Format Conditional Rules” section, towards the bottom).

The main benefit of using custom formatting over the arrayformula answer is that custom formatting just changes how the values are displayed and you can still do sums and other math equations with them, whereas once you concatenation a string onto the end of your number you cannot.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Correct in regard to now changing the number into a string.  However, the calculations can still be performed using the original column of numbers (which can be hidden - I know, not everyone likes the "helper column" thing).   I don't know that what @Nikhil Sharma wants can be achieved with the Format Number option.